# R shiny change showNotifcation font

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

How can I change the font of a notification in flexdashboard? I have notifications re: bringing in data, cleaning data, then generating a js table. I want to let the users know what's going on at each step. The css doesn't seem to get applied until the final table is ready and the notifications are showing in Time New Roman for all steps until the end.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

# Row
------------

```{css}
.shiny-notification-content-text {
  font-family:fantasy;
}
```

```{r}
library(shiny)
showNotification(ui = "Bring in data", duration = NULL)
```
````

[image]

I've also tried adding tags to the top of the code instead of the css chunk but it also didn't work

```r
tags$head(
  tags$style(
    HTML(".shiny-notification-content-text {font-family:fantasy}")
  )
)
```

Since I have you here talking about notifications... is there a way to show the notification without displaying this as an output?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/using.html#css-styles) you need to put the `css` in a separate file e.g. `styles.css` and then include it like this:

```
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
     css: styles.css
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it still does the same thing. The css seems to apply after things have loaded. I'll try to get more info from the developers on github